# C++ managing ifstream in a container with different object types

Tags: c++, class, containers, ifstream, radix

I have created several different objects of `Dog` and `Cat` inside the container animalColl. I am trying to workout how to adjust the file stream that is read so that if the object in the container is Cat then the catfile is used and Dog uses the dogfile. Currently, only the animalType passed into the parameter is used. Is it possible to choose which file stream is used based on the object type?

```
void Animal::load(std::string animalType)
{
    std::string file = animalType + ".csv";
    std::ifstream lstream(file);

    for (Animal *a : animalColl)
    {
        a->load(lstream); //uses one stream to read all the different objects in container
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `dynamic_cast` ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure why you're calling load recursively, so I can't give an exact answer. I think the answer you're looking for is going to be using polymorphism. This is a basic example:

animal.h

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Animal
{
public:
    void load()
    {
        std::string fileName = this->getAnimalFilename() + ".csv";
        std::cout << "fileName = " << fileName << std::endl;
    }

protected:
    virtual std::string getAnimalFilename() { return "Animal"; }
};

#endif //ANIMAL_H
```

dog.h

```
#ifndef DOG_H
#define DOG_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Dog : public Animal
{

protected:
    virtual std::string getAnimalFilename() { return "Dog"; }
};

#endif //DOG_H
```

cat.h

```
#ifndef CAT_H
#define CAT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Cat : public Animal
{

protected:
    virtual std::string getAnimalFilename() { return "Cat"; }
};

#endif //CAT_H
```

And an example usage (note that you MUST use a pointer to the base class to get the overriding feature of polymorphism, and you MUST declare a function as virtual to override it in the derived class).

EDIT: The below main.cpp was edited to use smart pointers because it used raw pointers and caused a memory leak, pointed out by @ArchbishopOfBanterbury.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include "animal.h"
#include "dog.h"
#include "cat.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> animalColl;
    animalColl.emplace_back(new Dog());
    animalColl.emplace_back(new Cat());
    animalColl.emplace_back(new Cat());
    animalColl.emplace_back(new Dog());
    for (auto &a : animalColl) {
        a->load();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
fileName = Dog.csv
fileName = Cat.csv
fileName = Cat.csv
fileName = Dog.csv
```

The basic idea is that you use the keyword virtual to override the behavior when using a pointer to the base class. So in my example, getAnimalFilename is overrided in the Dog and Cat class to return the correct string, rather than passing it into the load() function. Does that help any? Go ahead and reply to this comment and I'll try to help as much as I can.

Comment: You have a memory leak in `main`. Use smart pointers, not raw pointers, in this case - i.e. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>>`

Comment: Thanks, great catch. I've updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this. You could add an element to the class called name and strcmp this to check for type for instance:

```
struct Animal {
};
struct Dog : Animal {
    string name = "Dog";
};
struct Cat : Animal {
    string name = "Cat";
};

int main() {
    Dog d;
    if("Dog" == d.name) {
        //do something
    }
    else if("Cat" == d.name) {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Another way to do this would be if you know the type of another object, or are willing to create another object of type Dog or Cat, you can compare those types using typeid(obj) for instance, using the same structs as above:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Dog d, o;
    if (typeid(d) == typeid(o)) {
        //do something
    }
    else {
        //do something else
    }
}
```